# How can you reference template input variable 'hero' from *ngFor="let hero of heros" inside Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

How can you reference template input variable  `hero` from 
`*ngFor="let hero of heros"` 
inside Typescript?

I'm using a stateful component
So code has this for the 'heros' equivalent in my code is:

```
   servers: Server[];
```

It is populated when screen first appears via ionViewDidLoad.

When I add the server via button at bottom, ionViewDidEnter calls same loading method to populate servers again.

When debugging I'm going via ionViewDidLoad path.

[image: Chrome showing app with data]
[image: Template code with *ngFor and Event Handler]

[

Comment: which one do you want? you will have many `hero` variables for each `ngFor` entry

Comment: @Maximus - the one I've selected for editing...

Comment: The problem is that you are accessing the server variable outside of *ngFor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the Ionic documentation. on [ionic-item-sliding](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/ItemSliding/) you have to nest **<ion-item-options>** outside **<ion-item>**.

It ended up being a case of me putting the ***ngFor** on the wrong tag.

Thank you both **@Sajeetharan** and **@brijmcq**. 
Both your post sent me down the write path in the end.

**Html**

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let server of servers"> <! <<<-- Moved here -->
     <ion-item detail-push>
         <h1>{{server?.server}} </h1>
         <h2>{{server?.port}} </h2>
         <h2>{{server?.username}}</h2>
         <h2>{{server?.password}}</h2>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options side="left">
         <button ion-button color="primary" 
                 (click)="editServerConfigPage(server)">
            <ion-icon name="redo"></ion-icon>
            Edit
         </button>
         <button ion-button color="danger">
            <ion-icon name="remove-circle"></ion-icon>
            Remove
         </button>
      </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

**Typescript**

```
editServerConfigPage(server:Server):void {
    console.log('editServerConfigPage()', server);
    this.navCtrl.push('LoginDetailPage', {server: server});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can pass it inside a function

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heros">
  <li click="print(hero)">{{hero}}</li>
</div>
```

and inside TS,

```
print(hero:Hero){
 console.log(hero.name);
}
```

Comment: did it help you ?

Comment: Actually hero was undefined. Do I actually need the {{hero}} to make it work?

Comment: From the let of the ngFor I'd presumed... I say this as I want to pass a whole object, with it's associated properties - a value object...

Comment: probably a typo in "let hero of heros" ? I think it should be "let hero of heroes"

Comment: No I'm not. I'm using an event handler in an Ionic mobile app. Content from loop is rendering. I have a swipe left menu (ion-item-sliding plus ion-item, ion-item-options) that calls the edit handler. Placed debugger inside event handler. I always get undefined. Have tried ( $event, hero) as params as well as (hero). Always getting undefined...

Comment: @JGFMK could you create a plunker that showcases the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure how easy it is to create an Ionic 3 plunker. Have done in past with Angular..

Comment: @brijmcq - You can actually see some test data rendering, for me to be able to click on.

Comment: @JGFMK can you include the actual code instead of a picture?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the `server` variable outside of `*ngFor` loop that's why the value you got was undefined, because the server variable was unknown outside the `ion-item`. Try to insert the code `ion-item-options` inside the `<ion-item>` and it should work